# python scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to get names of restaurants, their addresses and their phone numbers.

My code keeps on getting stuck in the 2nd definition. The first def works fine. I am not sure why as I cant identify any mistake. The loop just does not go through.

I would appreciate someone to comment if I am doing an obvious mistake.

Thanks

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from csv import writer

def get_urls_of_restaurant():
    list_urls = []
    n = 0
    nn = 0
    for i in range(6):
        url = urlopen('http://www.go.co.tz/index.php/restaurants/masaki?start=' +     str(nn)).readlines() #open URL whis lists restaurants
        while n < len(url):
            if '<h2 class="contentheading">' in url[n]:
                list_urls.append(url[n+1].split('"')[1])
            n += 1
        n = 0
        nn += 3
    list_urls.reverse()
    print "Geting urls done! Get %s" %len(list_urls) + ' urls.'
    return list_urls

def open_url_and_write_data(list_urls):
    n = len(list_urls)-1
    csv_file = open('restdar_guide.csv', 'wb')
    file_writer = writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    file_writer.writerow(['Name'] + ['address'] + ['phone'])
    while n >= 0:
        print 'Reading %s' % str(int(len(list_urls))-n) + " element of %s" % len(list_urls) + " element's..."
        url = urlopen('http://www.go.co.tz' + list_urls[n]).readlines()
        num_str = 0
        list_write = []
        while num_str < len(url):
            if '<title>' in url[num_str]:
                list_write.append(url[num_str].split('<')[0][7:])
            if 'Location:</strong>' in url[num_str]:
                list_write.append(url[num_str].split('<')[1][9:])
            else:
                list_write.append('unknown')
            if '<li><strong>Tel:</strong>' in url[num_str]:
                list_write.append(url[num_str].split('<')[2][10:])
            else:
                list_write.append('unknown')
            file_writer.writerow([list_write[0]] + [list_write[1]] + [list_write[2]])
        n -= 1
    csv_file.close()
    print 'Done!'

list_urls = get_urls_of_restaurant()
open_url_and_write_data(list_urls)
```

Comment: Just when you thought parsing HTML with regular expressions was the worst idea ever, someone comes along and parses HTML with `split` and slicing. *Shudder*.

Comment: How about using a HTML parser, like [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/), BeautifulSoup, lxml, or the like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you abort the program, you are just going to get the KeyboardInterrupt error. Depending on timing, you could probably get the error to happen on any line within that one while loop - whichever instruction it is doing when you finally break down and abort.

Your program goes into a non-terminating loop because of this:

```
num_str = 0
...
while num_str < len(url):
```

You never change the value of num_str, so this is equivalent to `while True:`, for any value of `len(url)` greater than 0. This is, btw, a great place for a for loop.

That said, as others have noted, this is very much a non-optimal way to do HTML parsing / web scraping. There are a number of scraping utilities and HTML parsers available, and I think you might be better off doing so.

Comment: thank you for identifying my silly mistake. no wonder it went on an infinite loop!

Answer (score 4):

[BeautifulSoup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup/3.2.1) might make your live a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

The indentation of "`n = len(list_urls)-1`" seems to be too far, try to align it with the next line.

Comment: that was a typo in commenting. the problem still persists. this is the error i get after i abort the program:^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "restaurants_darguide.py", line 66, in <module>
    open_url_and_write_data(list_urls)
  File "restaurants_darguide.py", line 56, in open_url_and_write_data
    if '<li><strong>Tel:</strong>' in url[num_str]:
KeyboardInterrupt